# How to split content of 1 text file into different PCollections using Apache Beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I just started learning on Apache Beam using Python and stuck with this problem for a while, hope to get some help from anyone who is good in Apache Beam.

This is my problem statement:

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
BEGIN=burger
blue
lettuce
mayonise 
END=burger
BEGIN=fish
green
strawberry
ketchup
END=fish
```

May I know how could I use apache beam to split burger and fish into different PCollections so that I can perform different operations to these 2 PCollections?

Here I attach with my code snippets in Python

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import Create, Map, ParDo, Filter
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText

class SplitRow(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self,element):
    return element.splitlines()


def ExtractBurger(element):
    if element == "BEGIN=burger":
        return element

p = beam.Pipeline()
squares = (
    p 
#     | "Read From Text" >> ReadFromText("gs://abc.txt")
    | "Create dummy text file" >> Create([
          'BEGIN=burger',
          'blue',
          'lettuce',
          'mayonise',
          'END=burger',
          'BEGIN=fish',
          'green',
          'strawberry',
          'ketchup',
          'END=fish',
      ])
    | "Decode and split lines" >> ParDo(SplitRow())
    | "Extract out Burger" >> Filter(ExtractBurger)
    | Map(print)
)
p.run()
```

My output is this

```
BEGIN=burger
```

I am able to extract out the rows which has "BEGIN=burger" but what I really want is to extract out all the data between "BEGIN=burger" to "END=burger" into 1 PCollection and "BEGIN=fish" to "END=fish" into another PCollection, not sure if it's possible to do it as I feel like Apache Beam could only do row operations, how do I write a logic that does something like this

1. If found BEGIN=burger
2. Continue to loop through next rows until you find END=burger
3. Take the whole section and write it into a PCollection

Appreciate if anyone could give some insights! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beam processes elements in parallel. So there is no guarantee that it will process row by row in their original order.

To achieve this, you'd have to use a state (https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/) to record whether the current processing is in-between the BEGIN and END. And you have to make sure the parallelism is 1 for Beam and its runner (whichever runner you choose) so that it does not process elements in parallel.
But that defeats the purpose of using Beam.

- If you cannot change the file: you can just write a Python script to do this.
- If you can change the behavior that produces the file: you can give a uuid for each row between a "BEGIN" and "END". And your file doesn't even need to contain rows in their original order.
  For example:

  ```
     'burger=blue',
     'burger=lettuce',
     'burger=mayonise',
     'fish=green',
     'fish=strawberry',
     'fish=ketchup',
     'burger=pickle',
     'fish=chips',
  ```

Then you can process all rows in parallel, parse them into `{key}={value}`, and group by key into a PCollection that contains everything for further transforms.

Comment: Hi @大ドア東, appreciate your reply! I was using cloud functions through Python previously but I could not anticipate the memory usage of each execution as the input file size always varies, so I was exploring if dataflow could help to solve this issue through its parallelism and auto scaling. 

Theoretically, I could pre-process the file as you mentioned into the format as you show  above but I do not really understand on the uuid part? As my files have more than 1 burger or fish sometimes so not sure if I could differentiate between the two burgers if I put as {key}={value} pair. Thank you!

Comment: Got it! Yeah, if you have more than 1 burger or fish, you might want to organize them as `${uuid}${delimiter}${type[burger|fish]}${delimiter}${value}`. The uuid could be something like an order id or a hash of current timestamp. Then you can parse each row and organize them into structured entities.

Comment: Understood now. Thank you so much for all your help and advices! Let me think how I could better design my solution :)